# Sails.js, MongoDb: timeout when trying to connect; possible to use the connection pool?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, database-connection, sails-mongo

Sails server:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Sails.js 1.0.0-36
- Node.js 6.10.2

MongoDB server:

- Centos 7 on Virtualbox, host networking only
- Mongodb 3.4.4, listening to all interfaces, no auth configured

**I can successfully lift Sails, connect the datastore, and use the models without any problem.**

However, this test will result on a timeout:

```
  let mongo = require('mongodb');


  let uri = 'mongodb://'  + process.env.MONGO_SERVER + ':' + process.env.MONGO_PORT + '/sails';

  mongo.MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
    if(err){


      return res.serverError(err);
    }
    return res.json("open");

  });


{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [192.168.99.2:27027] on first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.99.2:27027]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (....\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:329:35)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (....\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:280:12)
    at Connection.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:191:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (....\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:187:49)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1281:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'failed to connect to server [192.168.99.2:27027] on first connect [MongoError: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.168.99.2:27027]' }
```

I am using the exact same server information used on the datastore.

So what could be wrong here?

And as important: is it possible to use the global Sails connection pool instead of creating a new connection? How? I have searched the documentation but cannot find specific references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code was wrong -- using port 27027, while it should be 27017.

Datastore connection worked because of a correct fallback I didn't notice

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test", function(err, db) {
  test.equal(null, err);
  test.ok(db != null);

});
```

Ref : [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect)

Comment: `err` is definitely not `null` --- that's the error I am getting, no need to test for it in a different way, thanks.